# How to update a scheduled script query including DML statements in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a couple of scripts scheduled as scheduled queries in BigQuery. I need to update some of the scripts and sometimes I run into an error where BigQuery doesn't seem to recognize my queries as scripts. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries), a query that includes DML/DDL statements should not have a destination table configured. However, BigQuery is forcing me to input a destination table, which I don't think I am supposed to do, as per above-mentioned documentation and since my script already includes an INSERT statement.

Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[BigQuery screenshot trying to update a DML scheduled script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3wdm.png)

On the left I have highlighted my script, which included DML, and on the right, the options that BigQuery is forcing me to fill.

What should I do in order to correctly update a script with DML statements, without having to input a destination table in the options?

Comment: If you're on the "preview UI", click from the "SQL workspace" page the top button "HIDE PREVIEW FEATURES" to switch back to regular UI, it may solve the problem. (You may need to recreate the scheduled query depending on what you did on the new UI).

Comment: Hi Yun, thanks for your feedback. I reverted to the previous UI and was able to correctly update the scheduled query as per your recommendation. Thanks!